# How to insert/show HTML element in a TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a feature I'm trying to develop in a flutter that allows users to @ someone in a note they are leaving, just like many messaging apps like Slack, etc. In this scenario, they would be able to type in the TextFormField, and then from a separate UI element, select a user to include.

In the TextFormField, it would appear something like this:

[image]

I don't currently see a way how I could implement this? TextField and TextFormField seem to only support Strings. Again, the use-case would be where from a list of people, they could select one/more..and wherever the cursor is in the text form field, it would insert the HTML element/or whatever element that could display background color, etc.

Any ideas?

Note that I've researched a number of html editors, such as  html_editor_enhanced, but they seem very clunky/overkill for something this simple.

---

Answer (score 2):

After further research, I found the following article, which walks through a nice clean solution on how to do this:

https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/tutorials/styling-parts-of-a-textfield/2021/101326/

You can basically use the example he provided, but then you just need to change the regular expression to look for any words starting with @ symbol per below. Note that I kept the first expression which changes the color of the punctuation, but the cool thing is, you can define any number of styles and regular expressions to change format dynamically.

```
final TextEditingController textEditingController =
        StyleableTextFieldController(
      styles: TextPartStyleDefinitions(
        definitionList: <TextPartStyleDefinition>[
          TextPartStyleDefinition(
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.green,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            pattern: '[\.,\?\!]',
          ),
          TextPartStyleDefinition(
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(65, 131, 196, 1),
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(232, 245, 250, 1),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            pattern: r'\@(\w+)'
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this package called [extended_text_field](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_text_field), seems to do what you want to achieve.

If you don't want to use a package, you can read its source code and extract the relevant parts.

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. I ended up using the approach outlined in this article: https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/tutorials/styling-parts-of-a-textfield/2021/101326/ . It removes the need for another dependency and also provides a more flexible/dynamic approach to styling the text in the controller.

Comment: @mikehennessy that's cool! If you could write an answer with a code snippet that achieves what you had in the screenshot in your question, you should then accept your own answer.